# My JAR file won't execute even if i double clicked or export as an exe file

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, executable

I tried to execute  my program which i made with **netbeans** but the executable JAR file won't run. i cleaned and build the project and tried but nothing happens. does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: while creating the jar file, do you mention the main method that will be called? I hope you are calling  the correct method...how did you know that it is not working? is that a GUI based desktop app or what?

Comment: Did you set java environment variable correctly.You can check in cmd. 1) java -version 2) echo %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: Oh yeah it has something with the main method. i changed the main class to another class and it worked. im confused why my main class did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running it by using the command line function?

```
java -jar <path to my .jar>
```

Comment: no, but i can execute other classes.. just this one class i can't